# In Flask, how can I pass a variable from template to Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, web-development-server

I have a list of profile name. When users click on one of the profile name, the application will load all the details of the profile. I also have a mySQL table on a database.

For example, if I have the following:

```
<li>
    <ul>Michael</ul>
    <ul>John</ul>
    <ul>Emily</ul>
</li>
```

The names of these three people, are the primary key of the mySQL data, I need to pass the name to Python in order to load the profile. I know how to get name using "onclick()" in JavaScript.

However, I have struggle on passing the variable from either HTML or JavaScript to Python.

The following code is a snippet of my "apprunner.py":

```
     app = Flask(__name__) 
     @app.route("/")
     def index():
          return render_template("index.html")

     if __name__ == "__main__":
           app.run(debug=True)
```

Assume that"li" is on the "index.html". How can I pass the name of the profile to "apprunner.py" as a variable? So that I can use the variable as a primary key to find the tuple in the database.

Comment: One way is to use javascript and a post request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass name using query params to your `flask` route

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/')
def data():
    # here we want to get the value of user (i.e. ?user=some-value)
    user = request.args.get('user')
```

You can pass query param using

```
window.location.href = "?user=" + selectedUser
```

There may be better solution possible for this use case, but this still *works*.

Comment: So, in "user = request.args.get('user')", is 'user' inside the get() a variable in JavaScript? Also, what file should I write the query param?

Comment: @ronnLee `user` will be passed from query params using the suggested way, which you can add in your javascript where you select user for getting profile

Comment: oh I see. So this line of code "window.location.href = "?user=" + selectedUser" is in the JavaScript file.

Comment: yes it will add query param which will be read by your flask app

Comment: What am I supposed to write on each of the <li> statement in HTML